# Повреждена куча, при отладке всё успешно. Как исправить?

Tags: visual-studio, c++

Здравствуйте!
При написании программы отладка проходит успешно, но во время работы вылазит ошибка и пишет, что куча (heap) повреждена. VS 2010 SP 1.

Код: usestring.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "String.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    String a("Hello, world!");

    cout << "String a: \"";
    a.Print();
    cout << "\", Len = " << a.Len() << endl;

    //===============================================

    String b=a;

    cout << "String b: \"";
    b.Print();
    cout << "\", Len = " << b.Len() << endl;

    //=====================================================
    b=a; //b.operator=(a);

    cout << "String b: \"";
    b.Print();
    cout << "\", Len = " << b.Len() << endl;

    //=====================================================

    b=b;   //самоприсваивание 
    //b.operator=(b);

    cout << "String b: \"";
    b.Print();
    cout << "\", Len = " << b.Len() << endl;

    //================================================

    a += b;

    cout << "String a: \"";
    a.Print();
    cout << "\", Len = " << a.Len() << endl;

//  a =  a + b;

    //==================================================

    String *p = new String ("Good Bye!");

    cout << "String in: \"";
    p->Print();
    cout << "\", Len = " << p->Len() << endl;

    delete p;

    system("pause");
}
```

String.cpp:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "String.h"
using namespace std;

String & String :: operator+=(const String &str)
{
    char *t = new char[n+str.n+1];
    //здесь д.б. обработка ошибка

    strcpy(s,s);
    strcat(s,str.s);
    delete[] s;
    s = t; n += str.n;
    return *this;

}

String & String :: operator = (const String &str)
{
    if(this == &str) //защита от самоприсваивания
    {
        return *this;
    }
    else {

    delete[] s;
    }
    n = str.n;
    s = new char[n+1];
    //здесь д.б. обработка ошибка

    strcpy(s,str.s);

    return *this;
}

//======================================================

String ::String(const String &str)
{

    n = str.n;
    s = new char[n+1];
    //здесь д.б. обработка ошибка

    strcpy(s,str.s);

}
String ::String(const char *str)
{

    n = strlen(str);
    s = new char[n+1];
    //здесь д.б. обработка ошибка

    strcpy(s,str);

}

String :: ~String()
{
    delete[] s;

}

void String :: Print() const 
{
    cout<<s;

}
```

String.h:

```
#ifndef STRING_H
#define STRING_H

class String
{
public:

    String & operator+=(const String &);

    String & operator = (const String &);
    String(const String &);
    String(const char *str="");
    ~String();

    int  Len() const {return n;}
    void Print() const ;

private:

    char *s;
    int n;

};

#endif
```

Ошибка (при отладке проблем нет):

```
"String.exe": Загружено: "C:\Users\Vladislav\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\String\Debug\String.exe", Символы загружены.
"String.exe": Загружено: "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll", Невозможно найти или открыть файл PDB
"String.exe": Загружено: "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll", Невозможно найти или открыть файл PDB
"String.exe": Загружено: "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll", Невозможно найти или открыть файл PDB
"String.exe": Загружено: "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp100d.dll", Символы загружены.
"String.exe": Загружено: "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll", Символы загружены.
HEAP[String.exe]: Heap block at 00294910 modified at 0029494A past requested size of 32
ОС Windows инициировала точку останова в String.exe.

Это может быть вызвано повреждением кучи и указывает на ошибку в String.exe или в одной из загруженных им DLL.

Возможной причиной так же может быть нажатие пользователем клавиши F12, когда фокус принадлежит String.exe
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как повредилась куча :)?
И как это исправить?

Comment: Можно комментировать код в main c конца и собирать Release-версию до момента, когда перестанет падать. Это укажет где именно проблема, оттуда и плясать.

Comment: у вас неправильно реализовано operator+=(String&)
будьте внимательны при работе с указателями, смотриче что куда копируете/присваиваете

Comment: Ребят, ну вы умные такие :).
Я понимаю что в этом ошибке, но где именно?

Comment: ОШИБКА НАЙДЕНА!

В первый функции я присвоил s=s а надо было t=s.
Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это не очень приятная с точки зрения обнаружения отладчиком ошибка.

Проверка на поврежение кучи работает так. При выделении памяти, выделяется места чуть больше, чем надо. При удалении проверяется, изменилось ли содержимое лишнего куска выделенной памяти. Поэтому такая ошибка обнаруживается только при удалении, и неизветно, в каком она месте. Искать её следует в циклах (ошибка на единицу, например i<=n, когда надо i<n), memcpy(копирование за пределы блока), strcpy и strcat(тут сложнее, надо знать длину строки).

Как ты уже понял, ошибка в этих строках:

```
 strcpy(s,s);
 strcat(s,str.s);
```

Тут у тебя и происходит запись за пределы буфера s.

P.S. Для чего пишешь свой класс строк? Задание такое или решил сам сделать для обучения? Для практики лучше использовать std::string. Он быстрее работает, хотя это и не предел. Я написал свою строку ещё быстрее. Для повышения производительности советую заменить strcpy и strcat на memcpy. Только про добавление нуля в конец не забудь.

Comment: Я изучаю Visual C++, это ДЗ - надо сделать всевозможные варианты сложения строк и получения их длины.